# What is the best practice for dealing with BizTalk 2010 Service Pack and Cumulative Updates?

Tags: service-pack, biztalk

What is the recommend approach in regards to applying BizTalk 2010 Service Packs and Cumulative Updates? i.e. should the latest cumulative update be applied regardless whether experiencing issues or not?

Comment: Since I'm about to patch a production BTS2009, I would like to know the answer as well. I also wonder if a cummulative update (CU) also includes all previous CU packs. The name implies it but MS doesn't explicitly state this.

Comment: @MarioDS Yes, CU's contain all the fixes from previous CUs, so you only ever need to install the latest one

Answer (score 1):

Yes, best practice is to install the latest Cumulative Update for BizTalk after first testing it in your test environment.  One of the reasons for this, is that if you ever do encounter an issue in your production environment and raise an issue with Microsoft, one of the first things they will want is that you are on the latest CU, if you aren't then they will want you to try that first.

**[Support for service packs and cumulative updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/biztalk/biztalk-hotfixes-cumulative-update#support-for-service-packs-and-cumulative-updates)**

> BizTalk Server supports all service packs, cumulative updates, security updates, and hotfixes. We encourage you to install the latest updates for Windows, SQL Server, Visual Studio, or any installed program. Service packs for Microsoft products are supported based on the baseline support for that product.